# java regex optional and pipe not working

Tags: java, regex

Ahoy everyone, 
I have the following regex pattern

```
String pattern1 = "([0-9+\\s|\\s])integer";
```

that I'm using on a string below. It suppose to select "integer" and a number followed by empty space before it, or just empty space if no number before it. I think I must be close, but I already spent all morning on it. Any help is much appreciated.
"BRTR   val  !http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# 78928458695   integer      integer  33  integer"

The trouble is that it could be an emptySpace+integer or number+integer, in no particular order.
The closest I came to is

```
"\\d+\\s*integer(.*)"
```

but that doesn't make it a pattern - it only works if there is a number before the "integer" and just gets the rest of the string, but I'd like to have it as a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `]` after the `9`:

```
"([0-9]+\\s|\\s)integer"
```

This matches with `"78928458695 integer"`, `" integer"` and `"33 integer"`, assuming that I got what you wanted.

An example:

```
String s = "BRTR val !http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# 78928458695 integer integer 33 integer";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+\\s|\\s)integer");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    list.add('"' + matcher.group() + '"');
}
System.out.println(list); // ["78928458695 integer", " integer", "33 integer"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this game me only one "integer" with no numbers, I need "78928458695 integer", " integer", "33 integer".

Comment: The trouble is that it could be an emptySpace+integer or/and number+integer.

Comment: @user2917629 It matches with those, look at the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

Given that either way you are checking for a space before the integer, you could remove that from the parentheses.

And now you're just looking for an optional integer, followed by a space, followed by 'integer', so you're final regex can be this:

`"[0-9]*\\sinteger"`

This matches 0 or more digits followed by a space, followed by the word integer.

Comment: This combination also gives me only "integer". I'm looking for  "78928458695 integer", " integer", "33 integer".

Comment: The trouble is that it could be an emptySpace+integer and/or number+integer, in no particular order.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I tested it on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, with Input 1 set to `BRTR val !http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# 78928458695 integer integer 33 integer` and the regular expression set to `[0-9]*\sinteger` and it catches all three, and returns '78928458695 integer', 'integer', and '33 integer'.

Comment: Yes, I just tested again. I'm using java 7. It returns space+"integer" only. I also test with Jmeter 2.7 Regex documented here: http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/scrapbook/jakarta-oro-2.0.6/docs/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/package-summary.html